# OL3: Is there a getUrl function for ol.source.XYZ?

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, openlayers, xyz

Problem: I am designing an ol3 plugin that needs to copy the URL parameter from `ol.source.XYZ`/`ol.source.TileWMS` to `ol.layer.Tile` on map initialization.

TileWMS: As per the [docs](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html?unstable=true), this is easily done with the following.
Note: not actual code, simplified for example. Assumes all layers are TileWMS with no layer groups.

```
var layers = this.getLayers().getArray();
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
  layer = layers[i];
  layer.set('url', layer.getSource().getUrls()[0]);
}
```

XYZ: In the [docs](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.XYZ.html?unstable=true), I see a setter but no getter. Currently I'm using `layer.getSource().setTileLoadFunction()` to gain access to the `imgSrc` parameter, which is the actual URL orf a loaded tile, and genericize it back into a template URL. This works with a single layer paired with one source, but breaks when multiple layers share the same source.
Note: Same assumptions as above.

```
var layers = this.getLayers().getArray();
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
  layer = layers[i];
  var oldGetTileLoadFunction = layer.getSource().getTileLoadFunction();
  layer.getSource().setTileLoadFunction(function (imgTile, imgSrc) {
    imgTile.getImage().src = imgSrc;

    layer.set('url', MyApp.utils.generateXYZUrl(imgSrc));
    layer.getSource().setTileLoadFunction(oldGetTileLoadFunction);
  });
}
```

Is there any way to have something like `layer.getSource().getUrl()` for XYZ?
Note: must use native javascript for solution, no external libraries allowed

Comment: There is a good answer here that may help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167792/how-to-retrieve-the-tile-url-in-openlayers-3