# How to retrieve the tile URL in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I have a question about Openlayers3 , I have the below code that initializes my map on my small demo application:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
            collapsible: false
        })
    }),
    view: view
});
```

You can see a demo **[HERE](http://purplefront.net/ol-3-demos/find-geo-location/)**

Now my question is how do I get the Tile url , so that I can store it locally using localstorage ? how do I get the Tile url ?

I saw the [ol.TileUrlFunctionType()](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.source.OSM.html#getTileUrlFunction) , but I am not sure how to use it ? can anybody help me understand how to get the tile url ? (can can play around in the Chrome Developer Tools for the demo that I have provided.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get the source with

```
// From the map we get all layers, then take the first one
// (index 0 in item) and then access the source
var source = map.getLayers().item(0).getSource()
```

Then, get urls with

```
console.log(source.getUrls());
```

We deduced this from [the API for the OSM source](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.source.OSM.html#getUrls).

**Edit**

To get each individual tiles, do

```
var source = map.getLayers().item(0).getSource()
var tileUrlFunction = source.getTileUrlFunction()
source.on('tileloadend', function (evt) {
    console.log(tileUrlFunction(evt.tile.getTileCoord(), 1, ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857')));
});
```

Where `evt.tile.getTileCoord()` is an array of `[z, x, y]`, `1` the pixelRatio (1 if not on Retina) and `ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857')`, the getter for projection used in OpenStreetMap. you can replace the `1` with `ol.has.DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO` in fact, to "automagically" get the "right" ratio.

Again, deduced from the API e.g the [`TileUrlFunctionType` part](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.html#.TileUrlFunctionType).
Forgot also to mentioned the [`tileloadend` event documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.source.TileEvent.html#event:tileloadend)

Comment: that workedd just fine , any idea , how to store the tiles locally ? in openlayers3 ?

Comment: OpenLayers 3 doesn't provide function for storing tiles locally. You will need storage from HTML5 (but limited because restrictions on data size you can store) or through a DB via direct access (like in Cordoba) or via a local web service

Comment: i don't see any method by the name of `tileUrlFunction` in the documentation , also that line throws an error . thanks for the tip though and yeah , the change event does fire !

Comment: You were right. I just forgot to cut & paste some lines, hence the wrong behaviour. Corrected now, confirm please? Tried on my side at http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/simple.html

Comment: works thanks :) but i must say openlayers has some danm complex syntax ... i meanso many objects inside objects inside object ! danm !

Comment: also what is `item(0)` exactly for , i am not quest totally understanding its usage ?

Comment: Usually for ordered content, you use a JavaScript array. Because of the code organisation (event management in particular), the OpenLayers 3 developers had to choose another structure for ordered list. This is an [`ol.Collection`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.Collection.html). So `item(0)`, could be considered as a way to access the first element of a list in the collection like you do `list[0]` for a JS array. You can see that `map.getLayers`  return an ol.Collection of `ol.layer.Base` http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.Map.html#getLayers

Comment: @ThomasG77 what is thet method item(0) ? , get the first key , value pair ?

Comment: `item(0)` get the first object (neither a key, nor a value: it's not something like a dict structure)

Comment: @ThomasG77 If I understood it good, this function will return loaded tiles. I am newbie in OL3. Is there anyway I can retrieve all loaded tiles for each zoom level and export it as GeoJson file? (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216911/how-can-i-retrieve-z-x-y-of-custom-tiles-and-export-it-as-geojson)